# What kind of brass instrument plays the intro on Hypnotic Brass Ensemble's Spottie?

Tags: instrumental, identify-this-instrument

I discovered [Spottie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWCKMzVRQ94) by Hypnotic Brass Ensemble. It is a cover of one of the songs by Outkast.

Can someone tell me what kind of brass instrument begins at 0:09 and makes this deep sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This instrument is called [Sousaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sousaphone).

[image: Sousaphone]

You can check the credits on [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Hypnotic-Brass-Ensemble-The-Heritage-EP/release/2316771) and see there is no bass guitar.

> Baritone Saxophone – Uttama Hubert
>     Drums – Eamonn Hall
>     **Sousaphone – Tycho Cohran**
>     Trombone – Saiph Graves, Seba Graves
>     Trumpet – Amal Hubert, Gabriel Hubert, Jafar Graves, Tarik Graves

You can hear a demo [here](https://youtu.be/d6FMsGffURE?t=45).

Comment: Tycho Cohran is actually pictured in the Wikipedia article on the sousaphone. :)

Comment: @ChrisSunami, you are so right! I haven't seen it first time.

Answer (score 2):

The group you are referring to is the Hypnotic Brass Ensemble. They have a website and a Facebook page, and a Twitter account. Why not contact them and ask them?

http://www.hypnoticbrassensemble.com

They list a [baritone horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_horn) and two [trombones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombone) in the ensemble. But they also have a bass guitar. This bass line sounds like the baritone horn, perhaps with a trombone doubling the line.

Comment: I'm actually asking because it has a very unique sound and it doesn't really feel like it's a brass instrument. (but I have just a little knowledge about these instruments) ;)